# featured channel URLs missing from YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have noticed that the YouTube Data API is no longer showing the featuredChannelsUrls list in brandingSettings.channel (in the actual reply, it's still in the docs), but I cannot find any deprecation info online. Anyone has any info on this or observed the same behavior?

Comment: The official API docs contains `featuredChannelsUrls` in `brandingSettings.channel`...

Comment: @AdamP. I know, but the API no longer seems to provide the actual data. I tested 5+ channels that used to work in the past.

Comment: hmmm... I think this is a bug in the API. I read the changelog for the API and the last modification related to brandingSettings.channel.featuredChannelsUrls is in 2013.12.05